# Offline client for Exchange Online archives

Tags: email, exchange, archiving

Exchange Online Archiving/In-place Archiving is a useful service and it keeps my mailbox compatible with the storage restrictions of a 32bit Outlook client (I cannot switch to a 64bit client due to certain plugins).

But I would like to keep a searchable offline copy on my windows desktop as well or mirror the archive to an IMAP server and access it via regular email clients.

Is there a way to automatically sync the Exchange Online Archives to an offline (Windows or Linux-based) storage?

Comment: Can't you just use the Auto-Archiving feature in Outlook?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the suggestion.  Maybe I should add, that I want to use both the online archive and additionally create an offline copy.  So your suggestion could work if I manage to enable both old-style archiving and online-archiving.  But I do not seem able to create the "old" archiving rules , Outlook 2010 always redirects me to https://outlook.office.com/owa/#path=%2foptions%2fretentionpolicies where I can only adjust the online archiving rules.